# Different behavior when selecting by mouse click and keyboard press

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have weird behavior using tags in the select2 plugin.

Tags are load by the ajax autocomplete. Ajax request returns tags: **tag1, tag2, tag3**.

I have chosen tag **tag1**. Now I type *tag* and in the autocomplete results list I have 3 options: **tag1, tag2, tag3** when I choose tag1 (this tag is already selected) using mouse tag1 is unselected (removed from select) but if I use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key nothing else is happen, only dropdown is closed (and this is ok for me).

How can I handle unselecting on mouse event? I want the same behavior as is in <kbd>Enter</kbd> press.

I found code that is responsible for this:

[mouse selection](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/04d582123d2df55c2b6b43c74c04d3d43f7dffd5/dist/js/select2.full.js#L1205)

[enter selection](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/04d582123d2df55c2b6b43c74c04d3d43f7dffd5/dist/js/select2.full.js#L5373)

Any ideas how handle it? It's a bug or a feature, for me it's seems like a bug.

Comment: Can you please add the code you have used and just upload an image that explains the issue.

Comment: Code is not needed you can easily recreate issue using provided by the select2 author example: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags